# Weird Python issue when using reload

Tags: python, reload

I can't figure out how to solve an issue I have when using reload in my program.
If my code is like

```
import mymodule
from mymodule import MYCLASS

x = MYCLASS()
```

then everything works fine. However if I try to reload the module like this:

```
import mymodule
from mymodule import MYCLASS
x = MYCLASS()
reload(mymodule)
y = MYCLASS()
```

I get some weird error. I understand that maybe is because the reference of `MYCLASS` and of `mymodule` have changed, but can't understand exactly why and how to prevent it.

What is the correct way to reload modules and classes imported in such a case?

Answer (score 3):

You should use reload in following style.

```
import mymodule
x = mymodule.MYCLASS()
mymodule = reload(mymodule)
y = mymodule.MYCLASS()
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

> If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import
>   ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the
>   objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the
>   from statement, another is to use import and qualified names
>   (module.*name*) instead.

**UPDATE**

`isinstance(x, mymodule.MYCLASS)` will be `False`, as the class is reinitialized, but `x.__class__` still references the old class.

```
>>> isinstance(x, mymodule.MYCLASS)
False
>>> isinstance(y, mymodule.MYCLASS)
True
```

Comment: +1. It's worth to mention that after doing something like this, `isinstance(x, mymodule.MYCLASS)` will be `False`, as the class is reinitialized, but `x.__class__` still references the old class.